# Skype 4.3.0.37 on CentOS 7 failed to open

Tags: centos, skype

I have installed Skype 4.3.0.37 in my CentOS 7 system. It's perfectly fine for one month. All of a sudden it stopped working and when I try to open it in terminal I get this error:

```
(skype:9353): Gtk -WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
(skype:9353): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita", Gtk-
Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Officially Skype 4.3.0.37 for Linux is [no longer supported](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c).

Unofficially you may run these commands (under root or sudo) and keep using it until Microsoft changes the Skype protocol enough to completely break old clients:

```
cp -a  /usr/bin/skype /usr/bin/skype.bak # to preserve the old binary
sed -i 's/4\.3\.0\.37/8\.3\.0\.37/' /usr/bin/skype # changes Skype version
```

Mind that with this old Skype client you won't be able to make audio/video calls with new Skype version. Chatting will work. Probably file sharing too.

At the moment the easiest way to use Skype without installing anything is to open https://web.skype.com via Google Chrome (Firefox is not fully supported yet).